# Why is my ToggleControl not showing up in Gutenberg?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am coding a custom sidebar in the Gutenberg Editor but I am getting this error thrown when trying to add a field. Here is the JSX code before I compile it. When I just have the `PluginSidebar` it shows but then get an error when adding the fields.

```
import { registerPlugin } from "@wordpress/plugins";
import { PluginSidebar, PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem } from "@wordpress/edit-post";
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";

import { PanelBody, ToggleControl } from '@wordpress/components';

registerPlugin( 'page-layout-plugin', {
    icon: 'smiley',
    render: ( props ) => {
        return (
            <PluginSidebar 
            name="meta-page-settings" 
            title="Gutenberg Settings Sidebar"
            >
                <ToggleControl
                label={__('Show Sidebar?', 'starter')}
                checked={props.attributes.showSidebarAttribute}
                onChange={(val) => props.setAttributes({showSidebarAttribute: val})}
                />
            </PluginSidebar>
        )
    }
} );
```

Here is the error it is giving me:
[image]